# Where are the 64 bit wix libs?

Tags: wix, burn

I'm creating a 64 bit bootstrapper application. The 32 bit version I've got linking to this:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.7\SDK\VS2012\lib\x86\balutil.lib
```

But, there doesn't seem to be an x64 equilvalent. Is it missing from the SDK install, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Burn is x86-only (so far) so bootstrapper applications must also be x86. So BalUtil.lib, which is used for BAs, isn't prebuilt for x64.

Comment: Feature request for x64 bundle support is here: https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/4579